# JQM: how to render a nested listview of 100 items in a reasonable time

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I need to display a nested listview with at most 100-120 items, each one with an average of 4 sub-items, using JQM. This is the relevant code I use (data comes from a getJSON() call):

```js
var groups = [];
$.each(data, function(i, group) {
    groups.push("<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='true'><h3 class='group-title'>" + group.group + "</h3>");
    $.each(group.items, function(j, item) {
        groups.push("<li class='news-item'><a href='http://exaple.com'>" + item.des + "</a></li>");
    });
    groups.push("</div>");
});
$('<ul/>', {
    'html': groups.join('\n'),
}).
attr("id", "list").
appendTo("#content");
$("#list").trigger('create');
```

On my not-so-low-end Android mobile, on a wifi connection, it takes 56 seconds to render!!!

I am rendering it dynamically; the rendered paged saved as a static html file (you can check it [here](http://www.resistenze.org/mobile.wip/staticlist.html)) does render in 22 seconds (which is not an option, and however it's still a lot of time...).

Since [JQM has discussed about deprecating nested listviews](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/06/14/jquery-mobile-update-week-of-june-13/), I'm thinking to drop them, too.

Which approach would you suggest to replace them? In the just referred discussion they suggest that "the same effect can be achieved [...] with our standard page model", but I find it quite generic: have you any more specific suggestion / example?

Comment: Are you using a up-to-date version of JQM? They improved the performance greatly somewhere around 1.0 - 1.0.1. -- No performace issue seen on S2 -- Checked the test page in the docs? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-performance.html

Comment: 1.2.0... The docs do not have lists with many items... However I'll double check my code against theirs, thanks...

Comment: Sorry, your reference just points to a list performance... :-( On my mobile, it takes 18 seconds to load a 500 items list (a flat one). So I can for sure profile my code, but I feel it's way too slow... Any suggestion for the proposed "standard page model" approach?